# Code design: How to ensure that DTO objects refer to the same object, avoid stackoverflow in circular references in Java?

Tags: java

I have a **Person** class which has a **Company** class which also have a **List of Person** .

Everything works great, the List have the same references to the parent Person. Not having any duplicate of Person. (I think hibernate achieves this, IDK)

Now in DTO, i want to copy the DAO (Person,Company) to (PersonDTO,CompanyDTO)

How can I copy the list of Person so that it has the same Person objects.

```
public class Person {
String name;
String address;
Company Company;
}
public class Company {
    String name;
    String phoneNumber;
    List<Person> Persons;
}
```

Comment: Maybe give us some sample codes so that we know what you are talking about.

Answer (score 0):

You can use external libraries for that like [ModelMapper](http://modelmapper.org/), [Dozer](http://dozer.sourceforge.net/) or [MapStruct](http://mapstruct.org/).

[Here](https://www.baeldung.com/java-performance-mapping-frameworks) is an overview of mapping frameworks.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. Using Mappers won't protect you from stack overflow on circular references.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using Spring or Apache Commons utils to do the copying:

```
public static CompanyDTO convertToDTO(Company dao) {
    return dao != null ? convertToDTO(dao, null, null) : null;
}

public static PersonDTO convertToDTO(Person dao) {
    return dao != null ? convertToDTO(dao, null) : null;
}

private static CompanyDTO convertToDTO(Company dao, Person original, PersonDTO converted) {
    CompanyDTO dto = new CompanyDTO();
    BeanUtils.copyProperties(dao, dto, "persons");
    dto.setPersons(new ArrayList<>());

    for (Person person : dao.getPersons()) {
        if (person.equals(original)) {
            dto.getPersons().add(converted);
            continue;
        }

        PersonDTO personDTO = convertToDTO(person, dto);
        dto.getPersons().add(personDTO);
    }

    return dto;
}

private static PersonDTO convertToDTO(Person dao, Company converted) {
    PersonDTO dto = new PersonDTO();
    BeanUtils.copyProperties(dao, dto, "company");

    if (converted == null) {
        converted = convertToDTO(dao.getCompany(), dao, dto);
    }

    dto.setCompany(converted);

    return dto;
}
```

It's pretty manual here, but it should get the job done. Also note that it may be more reusable if you create more methods that take in objects using generics.

P.S. I didn't test this as I wrote it directly onto SO, so it may not work, or may contain some typoes.

#### Edit

Usually, DTOs are created without any form of caching, even for non-circular dependency entities. That means if I have a list of `Person`, and there are multiple people with the same date of birth, the same `Date` (or `LocalDate`) is going to be created multiple times.

You can definitely do a cached of created DTOs:

```
public final class DTOManager {
    private final Map<Class<?>, List<SoftReference<Object>>> cache = new HashMap<>();

    public static CompanyDTO convertToDTO(Company dao) {
        return dao != null ? convertToDTO(dao, null, null) : null;
    }
    
    public static PersonDTO convertToDTO(Person dao) {
        return dao != null ? convertToDTO(dao, null) : null;
    }
    
    private static CompanyDTO convertToDTO(Company dao, Person original, PersonDTO converted) {
        List<SoftReference<Object>> c = cache.get(CompanyDTO.class);
        Optional<Object> cachedDTO = (c == null) ? Optional.empty() : c.stream()
             .filter(ref ->
                 ref.get() != null &&
                 ref.get().getPrimaryKey() == dao.getPrimaryKey()) // Use equal() if string key
             .findAny();

        if (cachedDTO.isPresent()) {
            return (CompanyDTO) cachedDTO.get();
        }

        CompanyDTO dto = new CompanyDTO();
        BeanUtils.copyProperties(dao, dto, "persons");
        dto.setPersons(new ArrayList<>());
    
        for (Person person : dao.getPersons()) {
            if (person.equals(original)) {
                dto.getPersons().add(converted);
                continue;
            }
    
            PersonDTO personDTO = convertToDTO(person, dto);
            dto.getPersons().add(personDTO);
        }

        if (c == null) {
            c = new ArrayList<>();
            cache.put(CompanyDTO.class, c);
        }

        c.add(new SoftReference<>(dto));

        return dto;
    }
    
    private static PersonDTO convertToDTO(Person dao, Company converted) {
        List<SoftReference<Object>> c = cache.get(PersonDTO.class);
        Optional<Object> cachedDTO = (c == null) ? Optional.empty() : c.stream()
             .filter(ref ->
                 ref.get() != null &&
                 ref.get().getPrimaryKey() == dao.getPrimaryKey()) // Use equal() if string key
             .findAny();

        if (cachedDTO.isPresent()) {
            return (PersonDTO) cachedDTO.get();
        }

        PersonDTO dto = new PersonDTO();
        BeanUtils.copyProperties(dao, dto, "company");
    
        if (converted == null) {
            converted = convertToDTO(dao.getCompany(), dao, dto);
        }
    
        dto.setCompany(converted);

        if (c == null) {
            c = new ArrayList<>();
            cache.put(PersonDTO.class, c);
        }

        c.add(new SoftReference<>(dto));
    
        return dto;
    }
}
```

This method comes with the cost of *accuracy* - objects in the cache may not be the most updated. You can implement your own cache, mine is just a simple example. My example is also **not** thread-safe, so you may want to take note.

In my opinion, it is not worth it to implement caching, since DTOs are supposed to be use-and-dump. This is only plausible if you are expecting retrieval of very huge amount of entities in a single transaction. Otherwise, it might be better to let it create more objects, then let the data transfer process take place, and thereafter let the garbage collector reclaim back those memory.

Comment: your answer avoids stackoverflow but why am I getting too many instances in memory of PersonDTO and CompanyDTO. For example, if I have 30 Person (DAO) and 3 Company (DAO), I think CompanyDTO should be 3 and PersonDTO should be 30. is this possible?

Comment: @InternCoder May not be what you want, but updated answer.